# How to find maximum date by joining table in my scenario in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have 2 tables.

1.#tempUnsold

2.ItemDynamic

These are the records from **#tempUnsold** table

```
ID      ChildId1  ChildId2  ChildId3
------------------------------------
111     112       113       114
221     Null      Null      Null
331     332       Null      Null
441     442       443       444
```

In other table **ItemDynamic**

```
ItemID         LastSold
-----------------------------------
112            2017-01-01 10:51:09.000
111            2017-01-23 10:51:09.000
221            2017-03-11 10:51:09.000
113            2017-03-23 10:51:09.000
114            2017-02-23 10:51:09.000
331            2017-03-12 10:51:09.000
332            2017-03-13 10:51:09.000
444            2017-03-14 10:51:09.000
441            2017-03-15 10:51:09.000
442            2017-03-16 10:51:09.000
443            2017-03-17 10:51:09.000
```

**Expecting output**

```
ID      LastSoldMaximumDate
------------------------------------
111     2017-03-23 10:51:09.000
221     2017-03-11 10:51:09.000
331     2017-03-13 10:51:09.000
441     2017-03-17 10:51:09.000
```

see this http://rextester.com/SVQK26958

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select Id,
       (select max(LastSold)
          from ItemDynamic
         where ItemId = unsold.ChildId1
            or ItemId = unsold.ChildId2
            or ItemId = unsold.ChildId3) as LastSoldMaximumDate
  from #tempUnsold unsold;
```

Your result row 2 seems wrong to me as you have no child record referenced.

Comment: eventhough there is no child, the result should display the parent item lastsold date. Any how there is a little changes only. have to add `ItemId = ID`. That's all. Thanks

Comment: Ah, the ID itself, now I got it. ;)